# When validate item go to record (Oracle Forms)

Tags: forms, oracle, triggers

I have a block from a table **(PRODUCTOS)** with these fields:**(PRODUCTO_NO(id),DESCRIPCION,PRECIO_ACTUAL,STOCK_DISPONIBLE)**

I need write a code on producto_no field and when executes "**when-validate-item**" this fill all fields with the correct data.

```
BEGIN
    SELECT producto_no, descripcion, precio_actual, stock_disponible
    INTO   :productos.producto_no, :productos.descripcion, :productos.precio_actual, :productos.stock_disponible
  FROM productos
  WHERE producto_no = :PRODUCTOS.PRODUCTO_NO;

EXCEPTION
    .......
END;
```

This works well, but I want to use, **insert_record, delete_record,** buttons and this dont "surf" for the database data.
Any way of go to wanted record to use on when-validate-item?

Another way: On my Delete button (On-press-button) I have this code:

```
BEGIN
        DELETE FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE PRODUCTO_NO = :PRODUCTO_NO;
        COMMIT; --2 VECES SI FUNCIONA
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    message('ESE REGISTRO AÚN NO EXIS EN LA BASE DE DATOS. NO SE PUEDE ELIMINAR.');
END;
```

This only works if I press the button two times, the first time not works :S

Sorry my english. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I haven't understood your question, but if you have a block based on a table and you wish to populate items based on the value of an entry from the same table, why not just used ENTER_QUERY and EXECUTE_QUERY?

Then have your DELETE btn simply do a DELETE_RECORD.

I'm confused.

Comment: My problem, that I select the data on the when-validate-item, and the block dont have a record on these moment, have my data writed manually. Then Delete Record not works. I don't know how get the record wanted writing the code on the field and pressing ENTER button. :S